# Delete SQL row in 1 days if it has null value or in 7 days if it has any data - Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am working with wordpress in database.

I have a table called `AAAedubot`
I currently have a function that is executed by cron
which deletes using the `time` table if it has 1 day.

Everything works perfect.

```
 function deletedatabasesession() {
 global $wpdb;
 $wpdb->query(
   "DELETE FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "AAAedubot
    WHERE time < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)"
 );
}
```

I need to modify that function so that if the table
`tracking` has data that you delete in 7 days.

But if the `tracking` table is null, delete it in 1 day.
How could I do it?

Comment: Q: How could I do it?  A: Maybe add an "AND" with an "IS NOT NULL" of some column to your first (1 day) query?  Then make a second query to handle the "7 days" case?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question the way I did but it would be the most optimal for a server with too many rows to make 2 queries??

Comment: "#/queries" does *NOT* matter has much as 1) whether or not you have good indexes, and 2) your query's "where" clauses can make use of them.  If you're doing a "full table scan" (i.e. not effectively selecting rows, and not using indexes) ... you're screwed...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way but I don't know if it is the most optimal for a server with too many rows

```
     function deletedatabasesession() {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query(
           "DELETE FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "AAAedubot
            WHERE time < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND tracking IS NULL"
        );
        $wpdb->query(
           "DELETE FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "AAAedubot
            WHERE time < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND tracking IS NOT NULL"
        );
    }
```

Comment: Q: Have you created an index on the "time" column?  Q: Have you run a "show plan/explain plan"?